# Rails - javascript injections

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2. I'm doing anything special when I'm displaying the content of my post, I'm just doing

```
<%=@post.content%>
```

When I add

```
"<script language='javascript'>alert('test');</script>"
```

to my post form of course it executes the javascript alert !

I tried adding the `html_safe` both before saving and before displaying but it didn't fix anything.

If I have to add any security code, will I have to add it before saving the post or before displaying it ? I heard that rails 3 was doing it itself so I didn't bother too much about security but I guess still there are some main things to be careful with.

Comment: It depends. Please show us your code.

Comment: I'll add it in a few minutes ...

Comment: Note that you should **NOT** use `html_safe` in this case. The javascript executes **BECAUSE** you are using `html_safe`. `html_safe` means "This HTML is safe, so you don't have to escape it." If you get rid of your `html_safe` calls Rails will take care of escaping potentially malicious content by default.

Comment: Thanks I thought it was the other way round... sorry about stupid questions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3 is quite strict about escaping anything you put into your view, but in Rails 2 and earlier it was your responsibility to do this. You have to escape everything using the `h` helper method:

```
<%= h(value) %>
```

When building an application that accepts arbitrary user input you **must** be certain you are escaping anything and everything that shows up in the view.

Comment: Unless OP is using a version of Rails less than 2.3.6, you don't need the h regardless of whether you're using Rails 2 or 3.

Comment: Good to know. I thought it was a 2.3.x thing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Rails 3? The javascript stuff should automatically be escaped.

But for more info on preventing XSS, I'd just look at [Ryan Bates' RailsCasts.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3)